# JQuery output into wordpress html wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, youtube-api, output

Trying to call the YouTube API to place videos on my website.

I'm using WordPress, my jQuery is in the functions.js file.

The videos load onto the page but they sit outside of my wrapper completely.

I want them to load into a specific div within my page.
`<br/><br/>`

So here's my jQuery calling the videos using you tubes API.

```
var playlistId = getParameterByName('playlistid');

jQuery.get("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" + playlistId + "?v=2&alt=json", function (data) {
    //console.log(data);
    var playlistData = jQuery(data.feed.entry);
    jQuery.each(playlistData, function (index, video) {

        // console.log( video.media$group.yt$videoid);
        jQuery(document.body).append(getVideoHtml(video));
    });
    //console.log(playlistData);
});
//$(document.body).append('hello')

function getVideoHtml(video) {
    title = video.title.$t;
    url = video.content.src;
    views = video.yt$statistics.viewCount;
    dateCreated = video.published.$t;
    videoId = video.media$group.yt$videoid.$t;
    // console.log(videoId);
    videoHtml = "<div id=\"videos\"> \
        <p> \
     <iframe id=\"ytplayer" + videoId + "\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\" \
      src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId + "?autoplay=0&origin=http://example.com\" \
      frameborder=\"0\"/> \
      </p> \
      <p>" + title + "</p> \
      <p>views:" + views + "</p> \
      <p>date created: " + dateCreated + "</p> \
      </div>";
    return videoHtml;
}

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Here's my HTML, not much in here but this is where I want the videos to sit

```
<div id="video-section">

</div>
```

And here's the output I'm getting

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="/images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <nav></nav>
        </header>
        <div id="video-section"></div>
        <footer>
            <div class="FooterLogo">
                <img src="/images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="FooterText">
                <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ad tota possim. Cu vis autem sonet soluta, sit libris debitis honestatis id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ad tota possim.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ad tota possim. Cu vis autem sonet soluta, sit libris debitis honestatis id.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="FooterIcon">
                <li>Icon</li>
                <li>Icon</li>
                <li>Icon</li>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <div class="FootersFooter"></div>
        <div id="wpadminbar" class="" role="navigation"></div>
        <script src="http://dopepreview.co.uk/wp-content/themes/The Basis/_/js/functions.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dopepreview.co.uk/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.8.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dopepreview.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.46.0-2013.11.21"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dopepreview.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.6"></script>
<div id="video-section">
    <p>
        <iframe id="ytplayer6-JfrvkX3u8" type="text/html" width="300" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6-JfrvkX3u8?autoplay=0&amp;origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </p>
    <p>Rory Sky Show - Caskey (YMCMB) London Interview &amp; Freestyle</p>
    <p>views:2301</p>
    <p>date created: 2013-05-08T14:56:38.000Z</p>
</div>
<div id="video-section">
    <p>
        <iframe id="ytplayeraajud6ks4z8" type="text/html" width="300" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aajud6ks4z8?autoplay=0&amp;origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </p>
    <p>The Rory Sky Show - Shystie Interview (New Music, Azelia Banks Beef &amp; More)</p>
    <p>views:1947</p>
    <p>date created: 2013-04-15T19:12:49.000Z</p>
</div>
<div id="video-section">
    <p>
        <iframe id="ytplayerRziNXcnMUbw" type="text/html" width="300" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RziNXcnMUbw?autoplay=0&amp;origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </p>
    <p>The Rory Sky Show - Sasha Go Hard interview in London</p>
    <p>views:1002</p>
    <p>date created: 2013-11-12T23:15:18.000Z</p>
</div>
```

The three videos sit outside of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you not change document body to "video-section"?

```
jQuery("#video-section").append(getVideoHtml(video));
```